# Is it possible to teach emacs to insert XML Code documentation in Csharp-mode?

Tags: c#, emacs

In Visual Studio, editing a C# file, when I type in three slashes in succession, it auto-generates a template for XML code documentation.

Can I get emacs ([csharp-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CSharpMode)) to do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a shot at implementing some logic to automatically insert XML comments in csharp-mode.  I've published it to [the EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/csharp-mode.el) as csharp-mode v0.7.2  I could have done this with yasnippet or some other template package, but I didn't want to tie  csharp-mode to a specific template package.

The behavior is that, if you type three slashes (`///`), then you get a template for a summary comment;

```
  /// <summary>
  ///   (point)
  /// </summary>
```

If  you then type three slashes after THAT, then you get a remarks section:

```
  /// <summary>
  ///   Lorem ipsum....
  /// </summary>
  /// <remarks>
  ///   <para>
  ///     (point)
  ///   </para>
  /// </remarks>
```

That behavior sort of mimics what you get in Visual Studio 2008, when you type 3 slashes. 
Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [yasnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet)?  It's a pretty extensible template system, with an easy to understand syntax.  You could have three `///` bound to the template you want.

Comment: Hey Trey, yes I have looked at yasnippet and actually use it for code template injection: for loops, foreach loops, while loops, etc. But, I didn't think to use it for comment injection, because I was thinking that the doc template I want is context-dependent. In other words, I don't always want the same thing.  But now that you've mentioned yasnippet, it's possible to write snippets that run elisp code, to determine what snip to inject. This may be a good approach.  Thanks for the hint.